# Press ctrl + c and save it to a texbox

Tags: c#, save, clipboard, copy-paste

I think I got Clipboard wrong but I would like to know or get a tip how I would need to implement this. I would like to have this program running in the background and every time I copy something it ends up in the program. That way if I would like to go back in time to see what I copied 10 min ago I'll find it in the program. So I guess I need to save it in a text file. How do I got about implementing this?

Comment: this question is so messy :))) deleting it yourself is the best way, the second best way is try to improve it.

Comment: That program would have to constantly be polling for what is in the clipboard. It also has to be prepared for non-textual contents. Should be possible.

Comment: Checkout some open source programs that do this already: http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Read [Cliboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648709%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) topics on MSDN to understand how it works and how to listen for new clipboard data. Than see if you want to translate it to C#... (Or you'll get better search terms...)

Answer (score 1):

C# can't normally raise events when the clipboard changes. You can read data from the clipboard, and you could busy-wait polling the clipboard, but those seem non-optimal to me.

However, with a little bit of `extern` usage, you should be able to get what you want. In a class which subclasses `Form`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Message id for data being copied to the clipboard
/// </summary>
/// <value>776</value>
private const int WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 0x0308;
/// <summary>
/// Message id for a window being removed from the viewer chain
/// </summary>
/// <value>781</value>
private const int WM_CHANGECBCHAIN = 0x030D;
/// <summary>
/// Message id for the window being destroyed
/// </summary>
/// <value>2</value>
private const int WM_DESTROY = 0x0002;
/// <summary>
/// The next window in the clipboard viewer chain
/// </summary>
private IntPtr nextClipboardViewer;

/// <summary>
/// Adds the specified window to the chain of clipboard viewers. Clipboard viewer windows receive a <c>WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD</c>
/// message whenever the content of the clipboard changes.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hWnd">A handle to the window to be added to the clipboard chain.</param>
/// <returns>If the function succeeds, the return value identifies the next window in the clipboard viewer chain. If an
/// error occurs or there are no other windows in the clipboard viewer chain, the return value is <c>null</c>.</returns>
[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SetClipboardViewer(IntPtr hWnd);
/// <summary>
/// Removes a specified window from the chain of clipboard viewers.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hWndRemove">A handle to the window to be removed from the chain. The handle must have been passed to the
/// <see cref="SetClipboardViewer"/> function.</param>
/// <param name="hWndNewNext">A handle to the window that follows the <paramref name="hWndRemove"/> window in the clipboard
/// viewer chain. (This is the handle returned by <see cref="SetClipboardViewer"/>, unless the sequence was changed in response
/// to a <c>WM_CHANGECBCHAIN</c> message.)</param>
/// <returns>The return value indicates the result of passing the <c>WM_CHANGECBCHAIN</c> message to the windows in the
/// clipboard viewer chain. Because a window in the chain typically returns <c>false</c> when it processes <c>WM_CHANGECBCHAIN</c>,
/// the return value from <see cref="ChangeClipboardChain"/> is typically <c>false</c>. If there is only one window in the chain,
/// the return value is typically <c>true</c>.</returns>
[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool ChangeClipboardChain(IntPtr hWndRemove, IntPtr hWndNewNext);
/// <summary>
/// Sends the specified message to a window or windows. The <c>SendMessage</c> function calls the window
/// procedure for the specified window and does not return until the window procedure has processed the message.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hwnd">A handle to the window whose window procedure will receive the message.</param>
/// <param name="wMsg">The message to be sent.</param>
/// <param name="wParam">Additional message-specific information.</param>
/// <param name="lParam">Additional message-specific information.</param>
/// <returns>The return value specifies the result of the message processing; it depends on the message sent.</returns>
[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

/// <inheritdoc/>
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD)
    {
        // The user copied something to the clipboard
        IDataObject clipData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        if (clipData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
        {
            // Copied data is text
        }

        SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
    }
    // Handle necessary native clipboard stuff
    else if (m.Msg == WM_DESTROY)
    {
        // Remove MyForm from the clipboard chain
        ChangeClipboardChain(this.Handle, nextClipboardViewer);
    }
    else if (m.Msg == WM_CHANGECBCHAIN)
    {
        if (m.WParam == nextClipboardViewer)
        {
            nextClipboardViewer = m.LParam;
        }
        else
        {
            SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}

private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Include MyForm in the clipboard chain
    nextClipboardViewer = SetClipboardViewer(this.Handle);
}
```

Make sure `MyForm_Load` is added as an appropriate event on the `Form` (most easily from the designer window).

Comment: Just a small note.  You can get rid of the need to subscribe to the FormClosing() event by trapping WM_DESTROY in WndProc() and removing yourself from the chain in there.

Comment: Good to know! I admit, I pulled this code from an existing application I wrote, removing extraneous bits. In my application, I'm doing other stuff in `_Load` and `_FormClosing` _anyway_. What's the value of WM_DESTROY?

Comment: `private const int WM_DESTROY = 0x2;`